# fail astype method to grouped dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I get following error when I try to apply `astype(float)` method to grouped dataframe in pandas.

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Do you know what is the reason why I cannot convert string to float by `astype` method? and how I can solve this?
Below is the code I get error and example data.

```
def group(self,agg_method):
    df=self.df

    grouped=df.groupby(['Tilt [deg]', 'Azimuth [deg]'],as_index=False)
    groupdf=grouped.agg(agg_method)
    print(groupdf['Azimuth [deg]'][0],len(groupdf['Azimuth [deg]'][0]))
    groupdf['Azimuth [deg]']=groupdf['Azimuth [deg]'].astype(float)  <- I get error here
```

Example data

```
   Tilt [deg] Azimuth [deg]  Glass SHGC  Area of Multiplied Openings [m2]  \
0        90.0        124.48        0.57                           1450.24   
1        90.0         207.3        0.57                            115.66   
2        90.0        207.47        0.57                            115.62   
3        90.0        208.25        0.57                             23.18   
4        90.0        208.26        0.57                            113.12   
5        90.0        214.48        0.57                            451.94   
6        90.0        218.57        0.57                            230.08   
7        90.0        304.46        0.57                             72.66   
8        90.0        304.48        0.57                           1827.53   
9        90.0         34.48        0.57                            917.29
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert non numeric to `NaN`s:

```
groupdf['Azimuth [deg]']= pd.to_numeric(groupdf['Azimuth [deg]'], errors='coerce')
```

If need remove all columns which are not parseable and no `NaN`s values in data is possible use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and filter by `notnull`:

```
groupdf = groupdf[pd.to_numeric(groupdf['Azimuth [deg]'], errors='coerce').notnull()]
```

In last version of pandas, `0.21.0` is possible use [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
groupdf = groupdf[pd.to_numeric(groupdf['Azimuth [deg]'], errors='coerce').notna()]
```